# How to remove PerformancePoint tab

Tags: sharepoint-server

I upgreded my SharePoint OnPremise 2016 to 2019 months ago. Today I created a new subsite and in the document library I find a new tab `PerformancePoint`:

[image]

How can I remove it? Please no jQuery or CSS hacks.

Answer (score -1):

The `PerformancePoint` tab is added to document libraries by default in SharePoint 2019. However, if you do not want it to be visible, you can remove it using the following steps:

1. Go to the document library where the PerformancePoint tab is visible.
2. Click on the "Gear" icon in the top-right corner and select "Library settings".
3. Under "General Settings", click on "Advanced settings".
4. Under "Document Library Advanced Settings", find the "Display "New Document" command on the New Button menu?" option and select "No".
5. Click "OK" to save the changes.

This should remove the `PerformancePoint` tab from the document library.

Comment: Sorry, cant find that setting.